# If statements: x is equal to sth or sth

Tags: if-statement

When I use the if/else statements, can I put if something is equal to 5 or 6 do this?

```
if (x === 5 or 6)
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Not normally no: in most languages it would be interpreted as `if ( (x === 5) or 6)` (due to operator *precedence*) which will always be true (since 6 evaluates to true).

Normally you need to write the more long-winded `if (x === 5 or x === 6)`.

Comment: if (x === 'existence' or x ==='Existence') i have this and it doesnt work

Comment: Use double quotations rather than single ones?